# How do I pass form url encoded parameters in a Redirect

Tags: scala, playframework

I need to do a redirect in my Action but also pass some url encoded parameters as below

```
 HTTP/1.1 302 Found
 Location: https://client.example.com/cb?code=SplxlOBeZQQYbYS6WxSbIA
           &state=xyz
```

How do I do this in Play?

What I have so far is in my Action method is:

```
Found("https://client.example.com/cb")
```

But then I don't see any methods to use to add the code and state parameters. How do I do this? I must add those parameters to the query component of the redirection URI using the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" format.

Or do I simply just add everything to the uri like this

```
Found("https://client.example.com/cb?code=SplxlOBeZQQYbYS6WxSbIA&state=xyz")
```

I thought there might be some special methods to add query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Looking in the source code, `Found` is really a call to:

```
Redirect(url, Map.empty, status)
```

So make your own `Redirect` would be the answer:

```
Redirect("https://client.example.com/cb",
  Map("code" -> Seq("SplxlOBeZQQYbYS6WxSbIA"), 
      "state" -> Seq("xyz")), 
      FOUND)
```